# PostgreSQL new Row based on previous Record Result

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

is it possible to create a new field `ballance`(**see the expected result in the bottom**) from query using this table?

**check:** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ed42ebefc7390b152d293ec1176f7c0

Table `Transaction`:

```
id      Usage         take  give 
------  ------------  ----  ----  
  1     Selling AAA   10    0         
  2     Purchase 1    0     40    
  3     Selling BBB   50    0
```

so the ballance on 1st record is `ballance = take(10) - give(0) = 10`

ballance of the 2nd record is, `ballance = 1st record ballance(10) + take(0) - give(40) = -30`

ballance of the 3rd record is, `ballance = 2nd record ballance(-30) + take(50) - give(0) = 20`

**Output expected** order by `id`:

```
id      Usage         take  give  ballance
------  ------------  ----  ----  --------
  1     Selling AAA   10    0     10    
  2     Purchase 1    0     40    -30
  3     Selling BBB   50    0     20
```

Comment: Please tell us what you want to achieve: Do you want to add a column to the table with the calculated data? Maybe you should think about views (or materialized views). Or use the new feature "derived column". So, you don't need to store the data twice and avoid data inconsistency.

Comment: thankyou for the respond, i think @Popeye already answered the question as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` analytical function as follows:

```
select t.*,
       sum(take - give) over (order by id) as balance
from transaction t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cd17d39e8a3347096a35df4187e4369c)

Comment: Woah, i didn't expect that the query can be this short...Working as expected! thanks!